# How to substitute values from a lookup table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have one table called `termData` with a `termID` field that is then used to join another table called `assessments`. However, sometimes the `termID` field won't exist in the `assessments` table. This is because I need the same assessment scores for one term to carry over into another term without needlessly duplicating the records with a new `termID` in `assessments`.

It looks something like this:

`termData / assessments
 1          1

 2`

Basically '2' needs to be aliased as '1' and then joined to the assessments table. I have a separate lookup table called `termTranslations` for this which looks something like this:

```
termID / termID2
1        2
```

To complicate things, sometimes there will only be one ID in the `termTranslations` table in the `termID` field i.e.

```
termID / termID2
3
```

In instances such as this, I need the query to just run with the first `termID` and ignore the null in `termID2`.

How would I write an Access compatible SQL query that does this? I would prefer to not resort to VBA.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you are complicating matters beyond reason, but you can use an _outer join_ to look up an ID in another table if it should exist and use `Nz` to replace a Null value (an ID that couldn't be looked up) with another value.

Comment: I am worried I am over complicating things, but our business processes are pretty complicated (not my choice). Basically I need new term records every term in the `termData` table, but I need them, despite the different IDs, to be tied to assessment records from previous terms. I will think about what you have said, though.